# C# How to call PowerBi Paginated Report and export to PDF

Tags: c#, azure, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

Does anyone have any good examples or links to help me print a paginated PowerBI report to PDF via C#.
I've done some reading
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-report-to-pdf-pptx-and-png-files-using-power-bi-rest-api/

I'm very confused.  I've downloaded the PowerBI API nuget package and tried some sample code, however I'm unsure if I need to create an app in azure or I can just call directly using my username and password...

My code to process the report will run in azure.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks

Keegan

Comment: You have an example just in the below menu item [Export paginated report to file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-paginated-report)

Comment: Hi McNets,  When I use the code in the link I have issues with the PaginatedReportExportConfiguration property in ExportRequest not being recognised. 
 VS error: 'ExportReportRequest' does not contain a definition for 'PaginatedReportExportConfiguration'.  The same error with the Client in 'var export = await Client.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(groupId, reportId, exportRequest);'

Comment: Is this helpful? [Power BI Export to file Error](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Power-BI-Export-to-file-Error/m-p/1169886)

Comment: Hey DeepDave-MT.  thanks for this but, no its not helpful for my situation.  I think I've underestimated how complicated printing to power BI is!  I cannot find any simple examples online for what I'm trying to do (print a paginated report from C#).